# AutoCADからのVBAプログラムの移植

Tags: vba, ijcad

AutoCADからIJCAD(32bit)にVBAプログラムを移植する場合、dvbファイルを直接読み込むことはできないのでしょうか？
いろいろ試してみるかぎりでは、frm, bas, cls等にファイルをエクスポートしたものを読み込むことは出来そうですが、
この方法しかないのでしょうか？ご経験をお持ちの方のアドバイスをお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

AutoCADのdvbファイルは、IJCADで直接読み込むことはできないようです。
言及されているように、AutoCADからIJCADにVBAプロジェクトを移植する場合は、
.FRM / .BAS / .CLS でエクスポートしてインポートする方法があります。
他の方法は分かりませんが、この方法で何か問題がありましたか？

参考：VBA - AutoCADのVBAプロジェクトをIJCADへ移行する方法について
https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/208277713